# How to link specific objects to RDF subjects?

Tags: mapping, rdf, rdfs

I want to describe a publication object along with all of its properties using some ontologies.

The ontologies that I chose to use are: dc, foaf, cito, dct, bibo.

So far this what I have done:

```
@prefix dc:      <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix db:      <http://lpis.csd.auth.gr/> .
@prefix foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix cito:    <http://purl.org/net/cito/> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix dct:     <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix bibo:    <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix map:     <http://lpis.csd.auth.gr#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix vocab:   <http://localhost:2020/vocab/resource/> .
@prefix publ <http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/ontology/publication.owl> .

@prefix atr: <http://localhost:8890/rdfv_pt/schemas/authors#> .
@prefix kwrd: <http://localhost:8890/rdfv_pt/schemas/keywords#> .
@prefix pub: <http://localhost:8890/rdfv_pt/schemas/publications#> .
@prefix ref: <http://localhost:8890/rdfv_pt/schemas/references#> .
@prefix rig: http://localhost:8890/rdfv_pt/schemas/rights#> .
pub:Publication a bibo:Article .

pub:PublicationID a dc:identifier .

pub:PublicationTitle a bibo:title .

pub:MediaType a bibo:presentedAt .

pub:publicationType a bibo:presentedAt .

pub:MediaTitle a bibo:title .

pub:MediaPublisher a bibo:issuer .

pub:MediaEditors a bibo:editorList .

pub:MediaVolInfo a bibo:volume .

pub:PublicationYear a bibo:date .
```

The properties that I haven't been able to describe with the ontologies above are the following:

- PublicationNoOfPages(Number of pages that the publication has)
- PublicationPagesInMedium (How many pages the publication occupied in a medium e.g. the book in which the article was published)
- PublicationFileName (The file name of the article e.g. pub.pdf)
- PublicationComments (Comments that other people made for the article)
- PublicationRelatedURL (Related URL of the article)
- PublicationRelatedURLText (Pretty much the same with the above only in string type)
- PublicationLocation (Where AND when the article was published)
- PublicationPubURL (URL of the article which was uploaded in a specific conference)
- DisplayOnMLKD (This basically a true/false value of whether or not it was displayed on a specific conference)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, and from a cursory glance, it doesn't look like the data you're showing is correct either.  E.g., you're saying that `pub:PublicationTitle a bibo:title`, but isn't `bibo:title` a property that relates a publication to its title?  You're treating it like a class, and saying that `pub:PublicationTitle` *is* an instance of the class `bibo:title`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor well yes what i am saying is that the field of the item "publication" that has the field "PublicationTitle" is like an object of the general ontology bibo that has the property title which is "bibo:title".
I am treating it like a class because the file that i want to create is a .n3 file that is later used to map an RDB to RDF and I am currently mapping each field to a general ontology.

Comment: **'the field of the item "publication" that has the field "PublicationTitle" is like an object of the general ontology bibo that has the property title which is "bibo:title"'**  I don't follow this at all.  A publication has a some properties.  PublicationTitle is a property that's similar to `bibo:title`.  If that's what you mean, then you want to say that `PublicationTitle rdfs:subPropertyOf bibo:title`.  Then, from `x PublicationTitle y`, you can *infer* `that `x bibo:title y`.  Or you could do that the other way around (bibo:title implies PublicationTitle), or you could make them

Comment: equivalent with `owl:equivalentProperty`, in which case each would imply the other.  If you have to treat a property as a class, then there's probably a modeling error somewhere.  Except in some very special cases (I can't think of any offhand), you shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I think you answered a previous question of mine before but anyway. You see I am following a tutorial about mapping an RDB to RDF using a tool named "Virtuoso". To do that I have to make the .n3 file that I stated above in which I need to describe a table in the form of rdf. This file is then processed by virtuoso using some SPARQL code that i have written and rdf triples are made which can be accessed later using SPARQL. In order to create the .n3 file that I will use in SPARQL I need to map every single one of the columns of the table to some ontologies that I chose.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor So yeah what i need to say is not that x bibo:title y but that the column named "PublicationTitle" of the table "Publications" is somehow equivalent to the bibo:title, because I need to produce linked data based on the ontologies mentioned above.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I *do* recall that question/answer.  However, this question makes no mention of that Virtuoso mapping feature, so all we had to go on was standard RDF stuff, and treating a property like a class doesn't make sense here in plain RDF.  I'm not sure whether it does here, either, but you should update the question to provide the context, in any case.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor can't you help me map these to any of the ontologies? :/
I have been reviewing the terms of the ontologies over and over again and I cant find any matching term to the columns that I need.

Comment: I'm not a Virtuoso expert, and that documentation is tentative.  You'll have much better luck if your question attracts people who know about Virtuoso, and since your question doesn't mention anything about Virtuoso's database mapping capabilities, it's not likely to do that.